# Creating multiple "configurations" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Context: I have an Eclipse project where I want make one build using file test1.c and another build using test2.c -- the project is otherwise entirely identical.

I noticed that in the Eclipse Project Explorer, if you bring up the context menu on a specific file (i.e. right click), it offers Resource Configurations => Exclude from Build... which sounds just like what I'm after:

[image]

So my question is: how do I create different "Configurations" so I can exclude test1.c from one configuration and exclude test2.c from the other?

My initial thought was to create a new "Build Configuration", but that seems to be more concerned about the choice of compiler:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: yes, "Build Configurations" is what I want.  I cloned `GNU ARM v10.2.1 - Debug` twice, renaming the copies `test-1` and `test-2`.

Then in Project Explorer => Build Configurations => Set Active to choose the version you want, clean and compile.

Works great.